# Why column not mention in groupby and sum will be dropped?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
    InvoiceID   PaymentDate          TotalRevenue   Discount     Discount_Revenue
0   72A04E22    2020-07-03 17:25:13   1650000.0      0.0          1650000.0
1   54FCFCB9    2021-03-17 14:26:08   5500000.0      0.0          5500000.0
...
```

After below aggregation, column `PaymentDate` is removed:

```
df.groupby(by=['InvoiceID'])[['TotalRevenue','Discount','Discount_Revenue']].sum().reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

How can I still keep columns not mention in group by or aggregation function?

Comment: You want sum datetimes? Can you create some sample data? Here in this data is not possible aggregate.

Comment: because 2 rows with different `InvoiceID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you’re doing a `groupby` with `sum` it means you’re aggregating data: from many lines with the same `InvoiceID` you’re keeping just one, with the sum of the values from all the rows in `df`.

Say this is your dataframe with the same row twice:

```
  InvoiceID          PaymentDate  TotalRevenue  Discount  Discount_Revenue
0  72A04E22  2020-07-03 17:25:13     1650000.0       0.0         1650000.0
1  54FCFCB9  2021-03-17 14:26:08     5500000.0       0.0         5500000.0
2  54FCFCB9  2021-03-17 14:26:08     5500000.0       1.0         5500000.0
```

Then you can see this effect on summing `Discount` for example:

```
>>> df.groupby('InvoiceID')['Discount'].sum()
InvoiceID
54FCFCB9    1.0
72A04E22    0.0
Name: Discount, dtype: float64
```

To answer your question specifically: **the column `PaymentDate` is dropped because you did not specify how to aggregate it**

- For columns that do not make sense to add, e.g. `PaymentDate`, you need to define another aggregation function to use. Do you want to keep the first payment date? The last one?
- Note that the `InvoiceID` did not disappear in the example above, you’re intentionally removing it in your code with `.reset_index(drop=True)`

Let’s say we choose to keep the last payment date, then use `reset_index` without `drop=True` to also keep the InvoiceID, we have:

```
>>> invoice_groups = df.groupby('InvoiceID')
>>> invoices = invoice_groups.sum().join(invoice_groups['PaymentDate'].max()).reset_index()
>>> invoices
  InvoiceID  TotalRevenue  Discount  Discount_Revenue         PaymentDate
0  54FCFCB9    11000000.0       1.0        11000000.0 2021-03-17 14:26:08
1  72A04E22     1650000.0       0.0         1650000.0 2020-07-03 17:25:13
```

That is all your columns, all aggregated in some way (either sum or max) from the rows in your original dataframe.

Comment: Hi @Cimbali, why after join I run this code and it output error KeyError: 'Column not found: False' invoice_groups[invoice_groups['InvoiceID'] == '72A04E22'] ?

Comment: Yes @NLeeT the `invoice_groups` are a groupby. You should use the result of `invoice_groups.sum(). ...` that should be in a new variable (e.g. `invoices`, see my edit)